# How can I show that any commutative ring R has a maximal ideal?

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose I have a commutative ring R and some ideal in R, say I.  I know that I will have to be a two-sided ideal since R is commutative.  I know I will have to come up with some sort of Zorn's lemma argument, but I'm not sure how to get to that point... ideally I would have some ascending chain of ideals in R, but I'm not sure how to come up with one given the information provided in the problem.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: You are assuming the ring has identity, yes?

Comment: Yes, the ring has an identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the poset $\mathcal{P}=\{I\vert I\triangleleft R, I\ne R\},$ which is nonempty because it contains the zero ideal. Now let $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{P}$ be a chain. If we set $$K = \bigcup_{I\in\mathcal{C}} \{x\in R|x\in I\}$$ then $K\subset\mathcal{P}$ and $K$ is an upper bound for $\mathcal{C}.$ Now use Zorn's Lemma and you're done.

Comment: A union of a chain of proper ideals is not obviously a proper ideal: indeed, it is false for rings without identity. We must be careful when justifying this point

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, it's enough to construct a partially ordered set (P) of proper ideals of R which naturally contains subsets that are totally ordered (ascending chains of ideals).  I take a random chain C in P and and I argue that the union of all the Ideals is an ideal, so my totally ordered subset has an upper bound.  Then by Zorn's lemma, P must have a largest element.  It seems so much easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski Yeap! And also note that as the previous comments say, we need to make sure $R$ contains $1,$ because that is necessary to prove that $K$ is a proper ideal of $R,$ so $K\subset\mathcal{P}.$

Answer (score 4):

Take the set of of all ideals in $R$ that are not $R$ itself, and sort them by inclusion. Now for any ascending chain of ideals, you can find an upper bound simply by taking the union of all these ideals, which is again an ideal, and this ideal is not $R$ itself, since it does not contain $1$. Finally, apply Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Where do we use conmutativity?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to use Zorn's lemma is that the union of an ascending chain of proper ideals containing $I$ is a proper ideal containing $I$.  That's easy, assuming your ring has an identity.  However, there are rings without identity that have no maximal ideals.